# Angular 5: What an example a directive change another directive?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular. In Angular document, they have stated that:

> Attribute directives - change the appearance or behavior of an element,
>   component, or another directive.

It's trivial for elements, components, but I dont understand about "another directive" (Although I know components is directives, but how about "real" directive). Could anyone show me an example about this statement? For example:

```
<div d1 d2> </div>
```

How can directive d1 affect to d2 behaviors?

Comment: components _arent_ directives, can you please clarify _real_?

Comment: Not entirely sure about the statement, but i think they mean that depending on what information you pass in with attributes `[someValue]="someInput"` etc can be used to affect the directive behaviour, as if you call a function, it can do different things depending on the given input value

Comment: @mast3rd3mon: "real" i means it has no HTML template, directives is components without HTML template, vice versa.

Comment: no, a directive _is not_ a component without a html template, they are different things entirely

Comment: Please refer to the document: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives and they stated that: "There are three kinds of directives in Angular: 1. Components - directives with a template."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means directives can be applied altogether and change each other.

For instance, in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uqduy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit-child.directive.ts), one directive creates a child, the other edits it.

You can play around with it and see what's possible.

Comment: Thanks you, this is my expected answer.